# Flutter google sign in id token invalid value

Tags: flutter, jwt, google-signin, flutter-android

I am developing google sign in feature in flutter and i'm able to extract id token from auth header but when i try to hit google api token info endpoint with the id token it's giving invalid id token as response but the accessToken is still working which is comming from the same header. Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

This is the code i'm using for extracting id token

```
 try {
      _googleSignIn.signIn().then((result) {
        print(result);
        result!.authentication.then((googleKey) {
          // print(googleKey.accessToken);
          print(googleKey.idToken);
          // print(_googleSignIn.currentUser!.displayName);
        }).catchError((err) {
          print('inner error');
        });
      }).catchError((err) {
        print('error occured');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Comment: Did you setup SHA1 key in firebase?

Comment: yes i did while creating the firebase app

Comment: Did you add email while adding the SHA1 key? and downloaded the google-services file again?

Comment: Yes i did actually you mean the support email for firebase right? i did override the google-services.json multiple time after the configuration was complete

Comment: Yes, the support email.It it allowing you to sign in into the app ? or even that is not working?

Comment: User is able to sign in properly but the problem is id token is showing invalid when i pass it to [google token info](https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo) as a param to check if it's valid and it throws id token is invalid but if i pass access token then it gives the access token info.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Vamsee. yes I did turns out my vscode was not displaying full token in debug mode i only printed out the token but when i passed it as parmeter it worked fine.